# Almost sure convergence of Bernoulli random variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence

Let $X_i \sim Ber(p_i)$ and independent. Prove that if $X_n \longrightarrow0$ $a.s.$, we have $\sum_n p_n<\infty$.

My plan is to use the fact the  $X_n \longrightarrow0$ $a.s.$ then  $P(|X_n|>\epsilon i.o.)=0$, which brings me to the following equation:
$$\lim_{n} \prod_{k>n} (1-p_k)=1$$
Can anyone share some thought about how to link the above equation with $\sum_n p_n<\infty$?

Comment: How is $X$ related to the $X_i$?

Comment: Take logarithms and approximate $\log(1 - p_k) = -p_k + O(p_k^2).$